# (Blender 2.8) Why is my smoke simulation animation not visible in flow type?

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

sorry if I use incorrect terms for my question, but i'm new to Blender and dont really know much of the correct way to describe them.

I'm currently following the Blender Guru tutorial series and i'm trying to put an object on fire. I did exactly what i saw on the video but no results. When i set the smoke type to "domain" (in the physics window) it shows the animation correctly but whenever i set it to "flow" nothing seems to happen.

I tried to restart Blender but to no avail.

I'm using a Macbook Pro (2015) running Sierra 10.12.3 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

For the smoke simulation, you need two objects.

One is the source of the smoke (Flow), and the other is the volume in which the smoke will appear (Domain).

The Flow object MUST be inside the Domain object, otherwise you will never see anything.

If you use the Quick Smoke option, it makes the selected object the Flow object, and automatically adds the Domain for you (typically a cube).  It's worth experimenting with Quick Smoke in a separate blend file or collection, just to see how it works.